# Pathfinding along a grid, with a twist

Tags: java, algorithm, a-star

Ive been scrambling my brains trying to figure out a way to find the shortest path between 2 points on a 2d grid. Ive seen posts about the Lee and A* algorithms but nobody anywhere seems to be able to answer my most prominent question. How can these algorithms be tweeked to work with decimal coordinates.

Everything ive seen has been simple whole numbers. But what happens when your trying to find the shortest path between say starting point (3.3, 4) and ending point (5, 4.6)?

Basically i need to find the shortest path between 2 points where the points contain decimals but you still have to follow the whole number grid lines. you cannot move diagonally, only north south east or west along the grid, but your not starting or ending on an intersection (like 1,1).

Think of a perfect city where each space between grid lines(each square) is a city block, and the grid lines are the roads you can travel.

Am I barking up the wrong tree with Lee or A*? Im extremely new to pathfinding and I am completely self taught. I know that reinventing an algorithm is beyond my scope at this point, but Im looking at my 80+ if statements and thinking "this cant be the way to approach pathfinding in an efficient manner." And testing out all possibilities using if statements is nearly impossible.

Any thoughts or website articles are welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: Keep in mind that at least one of x or y is gaurunteed to be a whole number, as you have to stay on a street, but you could start or stop anywhere in the middle of a city block (the decimal part)

Comment: Wow. put on hold as "too broad". Did you even read the question? It was meant to be a little broad, I was asking for pointers to good starting points, the more answers I could get the better. Im losing faith in this website now. and after 1 post!

Answer (score 2):

A* search should still work really well here. If you aren't yet familiar with the concept of graphs yet, I'd start by looking them up and understanding how A* search works on graphs. Many tutorials on A* focus on A* as applied to grids, but that's just one special case of how the algorithm works. It works equally well on general graphs.

Once you're familiar with general graph structures, the modifications you'd need to make to a grid-based A* or Dijkstra's algorithm to work in your case are relatively minor. You'd essentially just add in new nodes representing the start and end locations and connect them with appropriately-weighted edges to the four nearby lattice points. From there, you can run A* as usual.

If you're looking for a starting point, a while back I taught a class on basic data structures and graph algorithms and put together [some slides on Dijkstra's algorithm and A* search](http://web.stanford.edu/class/archive/cs/cs106b/cs106b.1136/lectures/25/Slides25.pdf) that might give you a good intro to the topic. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks! I will begin reading that tonight. Although glancing through it would be helpful to have explainations to go with the slides. but ill keep digging into A* and also check into Dijkstra